# IndexError - Works on Hombrew terminal but not on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, list

Hello everyone I have a python code that works on my hombrew terminal by setting up a virtual envitoment. This is how it looks like

```
python3 -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate
(env) python bandcamp_scrape.py
```

And it works great! However Im trying to do the same thing on https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ so I can automate the script daily it gives me weird errors and i dont know how to figure it out? Why does it work on my computer but not on pythonanywhere?

```
03:37 ~ $ python3 -m venv env
03:37 ~ $ source ./env/bin/activate 
(env) 03:37 ~ $ python bandcamp_scrape.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bandcamp_scrape.py", line 72, in <module>
    forum_login("Yakov", "test")
  File "bandcamp_scrape.py", line 15, in forum_login
    nonce = root.xpath("//input[@type='hidden' and not(@name='hash_passwrd')]")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Is your PythonAnwhere account free or paid? Is the website you want to scrape on the whitelist for the free accounts (if you are on a free account)? See https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/

Comment: im on a free account. the website is my own

Comment: And the other websitw that im scraping from is from Bandcamp which is whitelisted

Comment: Is it specifically `bandcamp.com` that your code is trying to access, and not (say) `www.bandcamp.com`?  The latter is not on the whitelist.

Comment: Yes its bandcamp.com

Answer (score 0):

Within the IO / filesystem context where the code is executed in pythonanywhere, `root.xpath("//input[@type='hidden' and not(@name='hash_passwrd')]")` appears to return an empty list.

It would be easier to determine the source of the problem if we could see the relevant code within `bandcamp_scrape.py`, but perhaps a hint to get you on the right track might be to examine if the pythonanywhere shell connects to the website properly, and if the HTTP response it receives is valid, and if it does receive a valid XML or HTML object for the specific request made before being put in the `root` variable.